# How to return tuple values from list

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to return tuple values1, values2..etc
One after another

```
def data ():
    List = [(1,"xyz",1.2), (1,"sgz",1.2), ...]
    return (1,"xyz",1.2), (1,"sgz",1.2), ...
```

Comment: `return`  will return `(1,"xyz",1.2), (1,"sgz",1.2)` as a sequence object which would be in sequence (one after another).

Comment: return should be sequence order of tuple

Comment: `return tuple(your_list)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yield` instead of `return`, like this:

```
>>> def data():
...     for i in [(1,"xyz",1.2), (1,"sgz",1.2)]:
...         yield i
...
>>> for x in data():
...   print(x)
...
(1, 'xyz', 1.2)
(1, 'sgz', 1.2)
```

Now `data()` works just like a list - each time you call `data()`, the next item from the list will be returned.

Comment: If `print`ing is the solution, why use generator? You could always do `for i in List: print i` in the function `data()` instead of `return`ing.

Answer (score 0):

Still can't figure out why you would want to do that. But if you want to assign variables to each tuple in the list, you could do the following (considering you know how many items the list has):

```
>>> def data():
        List = [(1,"xyz",1.2), (1,"sgz",1.2), ...]
        return List

>>> a, b, c = data()
>>> a
(1,"xyz",1.2)
>>> b
(1,"sgz",1.2)
```